# Type error in typescript casting a class that has static variables when using strictFunctionTypes

Tags: javascript, typescript

I just turned on `strictFunctionTypes` for my codebase and I got this error I can't quite wrap my head around.

I have an interface that is meant to be a generic presentation of a class (`ConstructorFunction` in the example below).
If I cast a class with static variables, I get a type error as shown below.
If I cast a class without static variables, everything is OK.

Why is this happening?

Code example below:

```
interface ConstructorFunction{
    new ( ...args: Array<Object>);
}

class HasStatic {
    prop: string;

    private static readonly bar = "foobar";

    constructor(prop: string) {
        this.prop = prop;
    }
}

class NoStatic {
    prop: string;

    constructor(prop: string) {

    }
}

// ERROR: 
//Types of parameters 'props' and 'args' are incompatible.
// Type 'Object' is not comparable to type 'string'
HasStatic as ConstructorFunction 

// OK
NoStatic as ConstructorFunction
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question about the original behavior: To cast from `A` to `B`, the types of `A` and `B` must be "comparable".  For present purposes, it's close enough to say that `A` is assignable to `B` or vice versa (i.e., the cast must be either an upcast or a downcast, not a "sidecast").

With `strictFunctionTypes`, neither `HasStatic` nor `NoStatic` is assignable to `ConstructorFunction`, because `ConstructorFunction` requires that the constructor accept any `Object` but the `HasStatic` and `NoStatic` constructors only accept a `string`.  However, perhaps surprisingly, `ConstructorFunction` is assignable to `NoStatic` because the parameter types of the constructor are more general, the instance type is implicitly `any` (which is assignable to the instance type `NoStatic` of the `NoStatic` constructor) and `NoStatic` has no other static members, so the cast from `NoStatic` to `ConstructorFunction` is accepted as a downcast.  On the other hand, `ConstructorFunction` is not assignable to `HasStatic` because `HasStatic` has a static member that `ConstructorFunction` lacks, so the cast from `HasStatic` to `ConstructorFunction` is a "sidecast", which is rejected.

Answer (score 0):

When using your snippet with the latest version of Typescript, your snippet first needs a little cleanup to get rid of the errors. Then we see the expected error:

```
Type 'NoStatic' is not comparable to type 'IConstructorFunction'.
    Type 'NoStatic' provides no match for the signature 'new (...args: any[]): IConstructorFunction'.
```

I think that there's probably a misunderstanding of a spread operator in a constructor. Below, you can find the cleaned script. Casting works and on the last line you can see how the constructor can be used:

```
interface IConstructorFunction {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-misused-new
    new(...args: any[]): any;
}

class HasStatic {

    private static readonly bar = "foobar";
    public prop: string;

    constructor(...args: any[]) {
        this.prop = args[0];
    }
}

// tslint:disable-next-line:max-classes-per-file
class NoStatic {
    public prop: string;

    constructor(...args: any[]) {
        this.prop = args[0];
    }
}

HasStatic as IConstructorFunction;
NoStatic as IConstructorFunction;

const instance = new HasStatic("mlkj", "lmj");
```

Comment: You should be able to reproduce the exact issue copying the snippet into:
[link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/)
and enabling the 'strictFunctionTypes ' flag. 

Changing the constructors of the classes sort of defeats the purpose of what i'm going for, but i appreciate the help nonetheless :)

If i change the interface to the following:

`interface ConstructorFunction{
    new ( ...args: Array<any>);
}`

the issue also disappers, and this is what i've done for now. 

The most important point to me is simply figuring out why only a class with static variables gives an error.